# Nan values in columns in python

Tags: python, pandas, nan

I have a data set which is created based on other data set. In my new data fame some columns have nan values. I want to make a log on each columns. However I need all the rows even though they have Nan values. What should I do with Nan values before applying log? For example consider the following data set:

```
a    b     c
1    2     3
4    5     6
7    nan   8
9    nan   nan
```

I do not want to drop the rows with nan values. I need them for applying log on them.

I need to have the values of 7 and 8 in the row 6 for example.
Thanks.

Comment: What is the expected output?, `df.applymap(np.log)` didn't work?

Comment: I was wondering if the nan values will affect my result or not!

Comment: It works, worked, you should first try before asking no?

Comment: I did not get the result which I expected. So I want to know Nan is the problem or something else!

Comment: You should post the results you were expecting so we understand what you are talking about.

Comment: I need to find the outliers in my data frame. I used interquartile range to find the min and max . However I did not get the expected result. So, I tried log before using interquartile range, again I do not have the right answer. I am trying to figure out what does affect my result.

Answer (score 3):

Having `nan` won't affect log when calculating for each individual cell.  What's more is that `np.log` has the property that it will operate on a `pd.DataFrame` and return a `pd.DataFrame`

```
np.log(df)

          a         b         c
0  0.000000  0.693147  1.098612
1  1.386294  1.609438  1.791759
2  1.945910       NaN  2.079442
3  2.197225       NaN       NaN
```

---

Notice the difference in timing

```
%timeit np.log(df)
%timeit pd.DataFrame(np.log(df.values), df.index, df.columns)
%timeit df.applymap(np.log)

134 µs ± 5.51 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
107 µs ± 1.79 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
835 µs ± 12.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

---

**Response to @IanS**

Notice the `subok=True` parameter in the [**documentation**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.log.html)

It controls whether the original type is preserved.  If we turn it to `False`

```
np.log(df, subok=False)

array([[ 0.        ,  0.69314718,  1.09861229],
       [ 1.38629436,  1.60943791,  1.79175947],
       [ 1.94591015,         nan,  2.07944154],
       [ 2.19722458,         nan,         nan]])
```

Comment: "`np.log` has the property that it will operate on a `pd.DataFrame`" where did you find that information?

Comment: So it's faster on a numpy array... :)